# Counting number of times value appears in an array using .forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I am trying to count the number of sentences in an array using the .forEach iterator on an array. Each time there is a full stop ('.') or an exclamation mark ('!'), it should increment a counter by 1. I was wondering if it was possible to do this using a Javascript iterator.

The array I am filtering through is called betterWords.

The code below returns 0 for some reason and I'm not sure why.

```
let sentences = 0;
betterWords.forEach(word => {
  if (word === '.' || word === '!') {
     return sentences+=1
  }
});
console.log(sentences)
```

Comment: What **exactly** is in the `betterWords`?

Comment: It was a string which has had a .split(' '); method applied on it.

Comment: @stormshadow854 None of the words in a sentence consist of only `.` or `!`

Comment: @Bergi yeah there's a word paired with a '.' or '!'. How would I isolate just the '.' or '!'

Comment: If you just want to count punctuation marks in the input string, you don't need to split it on spaces - just iterate the string characters. If you want to count only punctuation marks at the end of a word, look at the last character of each `word` in your loop

Comment: if (word[word.length -1] === '.' || word[word.length -1] === '!') {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution was almost correct:

```js
const betterWords = "Hello World! This is a nice text. Awesome!"
let sentences = 0;
betterWords.split('').forEach(word => {
  if (word === '.' || word === '!') {
    return sentences += 1
  }
});
console.log(sentences)
```

You can **not run `.forEach` on strings**. You can only do this on Arrays. With `split('')` you can **transform your string to an array**. `"ABC" => ["A", "B", "C"]`

Using Regex like @danh did is a faster way to solve this problem.

Comment: You can run a `for-of` iterator, which in effect is the same as `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

I gather that the OP aims to count sentences in a string by counting sentence-terminating punctuation marks like `. ! ?` (did I miss any?) A regex match will do it. Just count the matches.

```js
const countPunctuation = string => {
  return (string.match(/[.!?]/g) || []).length
}

console.log(countPunctuation("This is a sentence. This is definitely a sentence! Is this a sentence?"))
```